# Как по ASCII коду получить символ?

Tags: java, ascii

У меня в программе есть `JTextArea`. Также я из файла получаю массив ASCII кодов. Мне надо вывести подряд в `JTextArea` символы по кодам из массива.

Comment: Где у вас возникли затруднения? Покажите фрагмент проблемного кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayAscii.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(Character.toString ((char) arrayAscii.get(i));)  
}
```